# why won't my gui scale include tick intervals

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

my code runs perfectly but when i add in tick intervals onto the hscale the code crashes here is my code:

```
import tkinter
def main() :
    test_window = tkinter.Tk()
    test_window.wm_title("My Window")
    test_label = tkinter.Label(test_window, text="please enter bill amount:")
    test_entry = tkinter.Entry(test_window, width=10)
    test_label2 = tkinter.Label(test_window, text="tip amount by percent(%):")
    hscale = tkinter.Scale(test_window, from_=0, to=50, tickintervals=10, orient="horizontal")
    hscale.set(30)


test_label.pack(side="top")
test_entry.pack(side="top")
test_label2.pack()
hscale.pack()
tkinter.mainloop()
```

main()

Comment: Try `tickinterval=10` .

Comment: Code does not run 'perfectly'. As posted it doesn't run at all.

Comment: Down-vote for not actually reading the error message issued.

Comment: I got `NameError: name 'test_label' is not defined` did you test code before you put in question ?

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code.

Answer (score 1):

First: you put code with wrong indentions - next time use button `{}` to correctly format code.

Second: as @Goyo pointed out it has to be `tickinterval` without `s` at the end.

```
import tkinter

test_window = tkinter.Tk()
test_window.wm_title("My Window")

test_label = tkinter.Label(test_window, text="please enter bill amount:")
test_entry = tkinter.Entry(test_window, width=10)
test_label2 = tkinter.Label(test_window, text="tip amount by percent(%):")

hscale = tkinter.Scale(test_window, from_=0, to=50, tickinterval=10, orient="horizontal")
hscale.set(30)

test_label.pack(side="top")
test_entry.pack(side="top")
test_label2.pack()
hscale.pack()
tkinter.mainloop()
```